# How to prevent the input field from losing focus when the user taps elsewhere in the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, uikit

**How do I prevent an input field from losing focus when the user taps elsewhere other than the onscreen keyboard and the input field?**

What I would like to happen is that even if the player taps on a button elsewhere, the keyboard remains up, and when they tap on the keyboard to type, the focus is still on the input field.

I should also note that I am working with **Unity3D** and **UGUI**. I have built my Unity project and am modifying the iOS keyboard functionality via `Keyboard.mm`. I'm doing this primarily because how the `TouchScreenKeyboard` works out of the box from **Unity3D** doesn't fit my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about unity, but some things to try:

- When a keyboard is showing, remember the current focused field, and
  when any other element is touched, hand back the focus to the
  remembered field after the touch was processed.
- Remember the focus
  field, and when the user touches the keyboard again, set the focus to
  the remembered field.

Next to remembering the focus field and set the focus again when needed I fear there will be not many solutions, independent from the framework you're working in.